# Different page in different folder

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I read some tutorial in Google App Engine, in those tutorial there is same structure: each page point to each class, and ALL this class always same in `main.py`. I want to create new page on new file. So I do:

In project folder. I create `hello` folder, in this I create a simple script `hello.py` that has a class name `Hello`. For example this file is:

```
    class Hello(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.out.write('hello world')

    app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/hello',Hello)], debug=True)
```

But when I run this app, when I point to : `localhost:port/hello` I will receive `404:Error Resource not found.`.

If I define in `app.yaml`. I cannot deploy this app:

```
- url: /hello
  script: hello.app
```

So, please teach me how to run different file in different folder. in my example is `hello.py` and `Hello` Class in this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- url: /hello
  script: hello/hello.py
```

The `script` field should be the complete path to the Python file that your handler lives in.

Comment: I met this error when deploy, can you tell me more ? `threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: hello/hello.py`

Comment: although I haved changed `script: hello/hello.py` to `script: hello/hello.app`